# getting reads when writing to raw device

Tags: linux, dd, lvm

I need to move big chunk of data to a logical volume without any file system on it. While doing so, I noticed that on every write there is a read. This is something that I don't see for writes into regular files.
I narrowed down to the following steps:

```bsh
### Creat logical volume
lvremove -f /dev/VolGroup1/data_test
lvcreate -L 100G -n data_test VolGroup1

### Start dumping data
nohup dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/VolGroup1/data_test bs=1k count=100M &

### Check IO
iostat -h -d -k -N -y  -j PATH -p /dev/VolGroup1/data_test 10 1
```

Notice a lot of reads on that new volume by dd

```
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
dm-9
              56900.60    110719.28    116882.72    1108300    1169996
```

Does anyone have idea why this is happening? 
Underlying systems is raid10 of SSDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears LVM exposes a minimum I/O size. If you attempt to write to less than (a multiple of) this I/O size, then the system will first read the delta to fill the last block, then will update its content and finally rewrite it.

While I couldn't pinpoint the exact documentation about this, I could find a reference at [Redhat](https://people.redhat.com/msnitzer/docs/io-limits.txt):

> LVM will also detect the "I/O hints" for a device.  The start of a
>   device's data area will be a multiple of the 'minimum_io_size' or
>   'optimal_io_size' exposed in sysfs.  'minimum_io_size' is used if
>   'optimal_io_size' is undefined (0).  LVM will automatically determine
>   these "I/O hints" by default but this may be disabled through
>   lvm.conf's 'data_alignment_detection'.  Disabling this is not
>   recommended.

Some search leads to (here using dm-1):

```
$ grep ^ /sys/class/block/dm-1/queue/*_io_size
/sys/class/block/dm-1/queue/minimum_io_size:4096
/sys/class/block/dm-1/queue/optimal_io_size:0
```

So if for you, replacing with `dm-9` gives for example also 4096 and 0, use a size of 4k.  Or else if there's 4096 and a bigger value, use this bigger value for optimal performance.

So if you increase according to those values the `bs=` parameter there should then be zero read, and write speed will improve.

Comment: Thank you! This answer worked for me. optimal_io_size on my system was 1048576 and setting it to bs= increased my writes throughput 6 times. However, there still were some reads.

Comment: In the tests I made (on a simple dm, no raid) before answering, as soon as I used minimum_io_size there were zero reads. I'm sorry I can't explain why you still got some. You're supposed to mark the best answer that solved your problem  as accepted. But considering this, you don't have to. Somebody else might give a better explanation later.